# Angular 7: custom class decorator destroy component scope

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a decorator that on `ngOnInit` write a `console.log`

**log.decorator.ts**

```
export function Log(): ClassDecorator {

    // Decorator Factory
    return (target: Function) => {

        const ngOnInit: Function = target.prototype.ngOnInit;
        target.prototype.ngOnInit = ( ...args ) => {

            console.log('ngOnInit:', target.name);

            if ( ngOnInit ) {
                ngOnInit.apply(this, args);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

and a `HelloComponent` that use `@Log()` and import a service used in `ngOnInit`

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Log } from './log.decorator';
import { HelloService } from './hello.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<p>Hello! thanks for help and open the browser console for see the error!</p>`,
  styles: [``]
})
// if you remove @Log(), helloService.sayHello() works!
@Log()
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private helloService: HelloService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.helloService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

but this causes an exception:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined

if i remove `@Log()` from `HelloComponent` it works!

the decorator seems to destroy the component scope on:

```
ngOnInit.apply(this, args); // line 13: log.decorator.ts
```

after this call, `this.helloService` is `undefined` in the `ngOnInit` of `HelloComponent`, but without `@Log()`, `this.helloService` is a `HelloService` instance.

How do I fix this?

Live example on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hhp5n

Comment: I would rather say that there is no `this` context.

Comment: Try removing the ".prototype", so "target.prototype.ngOnInit" becomes "target.ngOnInit".

Comment: And concerning the first comment: There is a this context but most likely not the one you want. Use a normal function (not arrow function) for your new ngOnInit function as you want the this context to be the one of the class, not the one of your decorator (`target.prototype.ngOnInit = ( ...args ) => {` becomes `target.prototype.ngOnInit = function( ...args ) {` )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrow function forces context `this` to be the enclosing lexical context and it's execution context of `Log` function.

To have component context you should use simple function expression:

```
target.prototype.ngOnInit = function( ...args ) {
   ...
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztwu75?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**